# Move multiple images on Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, canvas

I am working on an Image based project.
I want to move multiple images on a canvas in the horizontal, line by line (left to right).

Here is an example code:

```
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import time
import cv2

win=Tk()
win.geometry("700x350")

canvas_1 = Canvas(win,width=600, height=60, bg="white")
canvas_1.pack(pady=20)
img = Image.open('image2.jpg')
img_0 =img.resize((80,30))
img_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_0)
img_2 = canvas_1.create_image(0,0, anchor='nw', image=img_1)

h,w = img_0.size
x,y=h,0
def move_fn(x,y):
    canvas_1.move(img_2,x,y)
move_fn(x,y)

win.mainloop()
```

I want to;

1. move images on a horizontal canvas (on x axis).
2. read an image and create that image on left side. When reading another image, the previous image moves to right with the latest image created on left side. This process should continue until the canvas has 10 images. At that point the rightmost image should be deleted automatically.

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have solved my issue,actually i want to move image without button.